# InvalidOperation Exception, Background Audio Agent, Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-audio

I'm trying to add a background AudioPlayer to a windows phone 8 application.

I've created the main project and the background audio agent. I've added a reference to the background audio player to the main project, and added the following into the app manifest file.

```
   <ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
       <BackgroundServiceAgent Name="myCastsbackgroundaudio" Type="myCastsbackgroundaudio.AudioPlayer" Source="myCastsbackgroundaudio" Specifier="AudioPlayerAgent"/>
    </ExtendedTask>
```

I've double and triple checked the references and I'm sure they point to the right things.

I'm sharing information between the two applications using IsolatedStorage and the following code

```
    private AudioTrack GetNextTrack()
    {
      string  myTrack = settingsHelper.Read("track", string.Empty);
      AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack()
      {
            Title = "Generic Title",
            Source = new Uri("isostore://"+ myTrack, UriKind.Relative)
      };
      return track;
    }
```

This would appear to pick up the track name fine, and then attempt to create the Audiotrack for playback. At this point, the application will throw the following error.

```
    System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
      _HResult=-2146233079
      _message=Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
      HResult=-2146233079
      Message=Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
      Source=Microsoft.Phone
      StackTrace:
        at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio.AudioTrack.set_Title(String value)
        at myCastsbackgroundaudio.AudioPlayer.GetNextTrack()
        at myCastsbackgroundaudio.AudioPlayer.OnPlayStateChanged(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, PlayState playState)
        at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio.AudioPlayerAgent.CallOnPlayStateChanged(ParameterPropertyBag parameters)
        at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio.AudioPlayerAgent.Invoke(Uri uri, ParameterPropertyBag parameters)
        at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAgentDispatcher.AgentRequest.Invoke()
        at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAgentDispatcher.InvocationThread()
        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
    InnerException:
```

For the life of me, I can't figure what's causing the error. Nothing jumps out as the root cause, and I've done this a couple of times for other apps with no issue.

Any advice or insight is appreciated.

edit: As requested, I have pasted the OnPLayStateChanged code below

```
     protected override void OnPlayStateChanged(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, PlayState playState)
    {
       switch (playState)
        {
            case PlayState.TrackEnded:
                player.Track = GetNextTrack();
                break;
            case PlayState.TrackReady:
                player.Play();
                break;
            case PlayState.Shutdown:
                // TODO: Handle the shutdown state here (e.g. save state)
                break;
            case PlayState.Unknown:
                break;
            case PlayState.Stopped:
                break;
            case PlayState.Paused:
                break;
            case PlayState.Playing:
                break;
            case PlayState.BufferingStarted:
                break;
            case PlayState.BufferingStopped:
                break;
            case PlayState.Rewinding:
                break;
            case PlayState.FastForwarding:
                break;
        }

        NotifyComplete();
    }
```

Also to add some additional info, the error is thrown at the creation of the audio track in GetNextTrack, so this code block

```
     AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack()
      {
            Title = "Generic Title",
            Source = new Uri("isostore://"+ myTrack, UriKind.Relative)
      };
```

Comment: Could you post the code you are using in `OnPlayStateChanged`? Which playstate is this handling (e.g. `TrackEnded`)?

Comment: Thanks Paul, I've edited to add that code. It's in TrackEnded at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AudioTrack` is very sensitive to edits on the track properties. You should use the constructor to set these values, or else use `AudioTrack.BeginEdit/EndEdit`.

So try:

```
    var track =
        new AudioTrack(
            new Uri("isostore://"+ myTrack, UriKind.Relative),
            myTrack,
            string.Empty,
            string.Empty,
            null);
```

Comment: Awesome Paul, that works. For completeness, I also had to remove the "isostore://" component as that's not required (this was in my original code).